# how to create dynamic table using headers as well in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[I want to have display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WpTd.png)

I want to select levels based on the machines from json .. I will get the data using ajax call from server.

### Below are the scenarios

Json response below :

{"MVXR":[{"levelId":1,"levelName":"L2"},{"levelId":2,"levelName":"L3"},{"levelId":3,"levelName":"L4"}],"CVI":[{"levelId":3,"levelName":"L4"}],"BPI":[{"levelId":2,"levelName":"L3"}]}

some times there might be empty response as well then i need to show all checkboxes as false

json response 
{}

I need some guidance how to do this all logic in angularjs ?

Do i need to use directive ? . I need to create headers as well dynamic.

Comment: You mean, you want to create the header of the table by the response you get from the server?

Comment: Not only headers .. I want to select the check boxes as well which are avialble for the machine ?  please have a look at the attached pic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first transform that JSON object into the object which is easily traversible using ng-repeat on the DOM to accomplish your output.

```
(function initController(){
    // calling the service and getting the JSON object
    var machines = {
        "MVXR": [  {  "levelId": 1, "levelName": "L2"}, 
                   { "levelId": 2, "levelName": "L3" },
                   { "levelId": 3, "levelName": "L4" }  ],
        "CVI":  [  { "levelId": 3, "levelName": "L4" }  ],
        "BPI":  [  { "levelId": 2, "levelName": "L3" }  ]
    };
    transfromReponse(machines);
})();

function transfromReponse(machines){ // pass your JSON object
    $scope.machineAndLevels = [];
    angular.forEach(machines, function(levelArray, key){
        var machine = {
            name: key,
            L2: false,
            L3: false,
            L4: false
        };
        angular.forEach(levelArray, function(level){
            machine[level.levelName] = true;
        });
        $scope.machineAndLevels.push(machine);
    });
}
```

And then traverse through this transfomed object using ng-repeat very easily.

```
<div class="row" ng-show="machineAndLevels.length > 0">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <td> Machines </td>
            <td> Level 2</td>
            <td> Level 3 </td>
            <td> Level 4 </td>        
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="machine in machineAndLevels">
            <td> {{machine.name}} </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="machine.L2"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="machine.L3"> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="machine.L4"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Here LevelName can be any thing as user can enter any data in the database . so in the transformresponse method i cant have hardcoded as key.

Comment: var machine = {
            name: key,
            level2: false,
            level3: false,
            level4: false
        };
        angular.forEach(levelArray, function(level){
            var key  = 'level'+(level.levelId +1);
            machine[key  ] = true;
        });

Comment: [{"name":"MVXR","L2":true,"L3":true,"L4":true},{"name":"CVI","L2":false,"L3":false,"L4":true},{"name":"BPI","L2":false,"L3":true,"L4":false}]